# CRC32+Size vs MD5/SHA1

Tags: hash, md5, storage, crc32

We have a storage of files and the storage uniquely identifies a file on the basis of size appended to crc32.

I wanted to know if this checksum ( crc32 + size ) would be good enough for identifying files or should we consider some other hashing technique like MD5/SHA1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space that would be used by a CRC32+size gives you enough room for a bigger CRC which would be a much better choice. If you are not worried about malicious collision that's it in which case Thomas' answer applies.

You didn't specify a language but for example in C++ you got [Boost CRC](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/crc/crc.html) giving you CRC of the size you want (or you can afford to store).

Comment: The language implementation is C. I'll look into BoostCRC. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

CRC is most an error detection method than a serious hash function. It helps in identify corrupting files rather than uniquely identify them.
So your choice should be between MD5 and SHA1.

If you don't have strong security needings you can choose MD5 that should be faster. 
(remember that MD5 is vulnerable to collision attacks).
If you need more security you better use SHA1 or even SHA2 .

Comment: MD5 has been proven flawed for half a decade. Don't use it or at the very least combine it with another method.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: +1 you are right. I would never use MD5 for anything. Anyway I think that @Rajiv's intention was not related to security. So, for a local storage, even MD5 could be enough

Answer (score 4):

CRC-32 is not good enough; it is trivial to build collisions, i.e. two files (of the same length if you wish it so) which have the same CRC-32. Even in the absence of a malicious attacker, collisions will happen randomly once you have about 65000 distinct files with the same length.

A hash function is designed to avoid collisions. With MD5 or SHA-1, you will not get random collisions. If your setup is security-related (i.e. there is someone, somewhere, who may actively try to create collisions), then you need a *secure* hash function. MD5 is not secure anymore (creating collisions with MD5 is easy) and SHA-1 is somewhat weak in that respect (no actual collisions were computed, but a method for creating one is known and, while expensive, it is much less expensive than what it ought to be). The usual recommendation is to use SHA-256 or SHA-512 (SHA-256 is enough for security; SHA-512 may be a tad faster on big, 64-bit systems, but file reading bandwidth will be more limitating than hashing speed).

Note: when using a cryptographic hash function, there is no need to store and compare the file lengths; the hash is sufficient to disambiguate files.

In a non-security setup (i.e. you only fear random collisions), then [MD4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1320) can be used. It is thoroughly "broken" as a cryptographic hash function, but it still is a very good checksum, and it is really fast (on some ARM-based platforms, it is even faster than CRC-32, for a much better resistance to random collisions). Basically, you should not use MD5: if you have security issues, then MD5 must not be used (it is broken; use SHA-256); and if you do *not* have security issues then MD4 is faster than MD5.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, CRC doesn't guarantee absence of collisions. However, your problem is be solved simply by giving the files incrementing 64-bit numbers. This is guaranteed to never collide (unless you want to keep gazillion of files in one directory which is not a good idea anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but still highly ranked on Google, so it deserves a modern answer:

If you want a ***non-cryptographic*** hash that's suitable for identifying files, better than CRC32 but faster than MD5, I truly recommend the [xxHash](https://cyan4973.github.io/xxHash/) family.

- Has 32, 64 and 128-bit versions, so regarding *random* collisions it is *much* better than CRC32 and as strong as MD5.
- It's much, **much** faster than MD5. By 10 times (or more) depending on file size. Heck, on some test files the 128-bit version was even faster than CRC32!!!

```
$ time cat       >/dev/null test1G.bin 

real    0m0.099s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.099s

$ time xxh128sum >/dev/null test1G.bin 
                                                                      
real    0m0.169s
user    0m0.113s
sys     0m0.056s

$ time crc32     >/dev/null test1G.bin 

real    0m0.936s
user    0m0.828s
sys     0m0.108s

$ time md5sum    >/dev/null test1G.bin 

real    0m1.554s
user    0m1.502s
sys     0m0.052s

$ time sha1sum   >/dev/null test1G.bin 

real    0m1.717s
user    0m1.616s
sys     0m0.096s
```

Besides the command-line tools it also has libraries for several languages, including C, Java, Python, etc.